# Get Index of last value that matches a condition in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to get the index of the last `nil` in an array. For the following array:

```
["Pending Verification", "Pending Verification", nil, nil]
```

the index should be `3`. Or in this scenario:

```
[nil, "Pending Verification", nil, "Bla"]
```

it should be `2`.

How can I do this in ruby?

Comment: FYI – Ruby has an excellent documentation, e.g. http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html

Comment: @Stefan Mmh, for "excellent" it's too often way too frustratingly bad. For example https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/ doesn't even list the Array class in its Class and Module Index.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yeah, seems like RDoc messed up the index. With "excellent" I was referring to Ruby's documentation in general, not a particular website. Maybe I should have said `ri Array` ;-)

Comment: @Stefan That's just one thing, I mentioned it because it fit the topic here. I *also* meant Ruby's documentation in general. Too much missing or wrong stuff. I do use ruby-doc.org most of the time. Newest nuisance *there* is that  it does document 2.4.0, 2.4.1 and 2.4.2, but *not* 2.4.3 even though that's been out for over two months. Didn't know `ri`, btw, but it only tells me "Nothing known about Array" :-(

Comment: @StefanPochmann Luckily we're part of the Ruby community so we can fix most of it. (BTW, ruby-doc.org is maintained by James Britt, you can contact him via suggestions@ruby-doc.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
a = [nil, "Pending Verification", nil, "Bla"] 
a.rindex { |x| x.nil? }
```

Comment: Or simply `a.rindex(nil)`